# Allow LAN users to access my VirtualBox using NAT+Port Forward?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox setup with Ubuntu + LAMP with OpenSSH.

I’d like my colleagues to access services on it—such as ftp, http, ssh…—through the LAN. I can’t setup the VirtualBox via network bridging because I don’t have control over the physical computers’ IP address (DHCP); We’re in the office and I don't want to bother talking to the I.T. department.

Can this be achieved with NAT and port forwarding?

For example, my physical LAN card's IP is `192.168.0.101`. Everytime computers on the LAN types that address, I want it forwarded to my VirtualBox with different ports for Apache, SSH and FTP.

Can this even be done without bridging?

Comment: well, you can definitely forward ports through the vbox nat, but you still have the DHCP problem. if your IP changes, you need to inform your users. If your IT dept uses DDNS (like active directory's DNS registration) you could just use the hostname though.  http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/?PageSpeed=noscript

Comment: If a LAN user types in http://192.168.0.101 in his browser, should it point to my VirtualBox port 80 and not the host computer's port 80?

Comment: if you don't have a windows service (iis or whaatever) on tcp\80, and correctly forward your appache port to 80, then yes.

Comment: Which is exactly my question :) How do I make the host, accessed directly by LAN peers, 'port forward' to the guest VirtualBox?

Comment: see the link in my first comment.